# How to edit EditText view inside SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listadapter, android-tablelayout, simpleadapter

I am working on simpleAdapter which is showing database list in table layout. I am successfully able to show this list in table layout. But now I want to edit `EditText` of this simple adapter. My table layout of simple adapter contains `Checkbox`, `TextView` and `EditText`. Right now I am not able edit EditText e1 inside this simple adapter. I want to set text inside this edittext e1 and set some value based of formula which is using previous edittext e1 which I am editing. This value should be set in another edittext e2 which is in the same row. My code for simpleadapter is as follows :

```
            ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList2,
                    R.layout.table_list_item, new String[]{
                    TAG_PRODUCT, "WMS",TAG_PRODUCTPERCARTON, TAG_UNITPRICE,TAG_PRODUCTPERCARTON2,TAG_UNITPRICE,cartonnumber,"No. of Products","Discount",TAG_TotalPrice,"Add","Check"}, new int[]{R.id.txtcustomerName, R.id.mycheck,R.id.txtorderamount, R.id.txtorderstatus,R.id.txtorderdate,R.id.txtorderby,R.id.txtordercarton,R.id.txtproduct,R.id.txtdiscount,R.id.txtprice,R.id.txtadd,R.id.mynewcheck});
            setListAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: You need to use your custom adapter instead of SimpleAdapter

Comment: But will I be able to show my list in table layout by making custom adapter?Because my list of database is in table layout which is using checkbox,textview and edittext in every row and thanks for your reply nabin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using listview.setOnItemClickListener and using android:focusable="false" inside xml file for edittext and checkbox.